# Need help editing Customer Info in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, oledb, sqldatareader, c#-to-vb.net

I am trying to edit customers using my C# project to learn how to implement this code in VB.net. The project was successful in adding customers, but when it got to editing customers, things got a bit more complicated because I needed to get the id of the row selected and pass it to a string. I have the MainForm.vb which could open CustomerForm.vb when I click on 'Edit'. When CustomerForm.vb opens, it failed to show the customer's info. I am not sure if `FillDataTable()` function is necassary, I would like to know if there is an improvement to this.

**CustomerForm.vb**

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class CustomerForm
Private objConnection As SqlConnection
Public objDataTable As DataTable = New DataTable()
Public objSqlCommand As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()
Public editMode As Boolean = False
Public id As String = ""
Public FName As String = ""
Public LName As String = ""
Public PhNumber As String = ""

Public ReadOnly Property Connection As SqlConnection
    Get
        Return Me.objConnection
    End Get
End Property

Dim CS As String = ("server=CASHAMERICA;Trusted_Connection=yes;database=ProductsDatabase2; connection timeout=30")

Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

    Try
        If editMode = False Then
            If txtFirstName.Text = "" Then
                MessageBox.Show("First Name Is required")
            ElseIf txtLastName.Text = "" Then
                MessageBox.Show("Last Name Is required")
            Else
                Dim con As New SqlConnection(CS)
                con.Open()
                Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Customers(FIrstName,LastName,PhoneNumber) VALUES(@FName, @LName, @PhNumber)", con)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FName", txtFirstName.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LName", txtLastName.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhNumber", txtPhoneNumber.Text)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MessageBox.Show("Customer has been added!")
                con.Close()
            End If
        ElseIf editMode = True Then
            If txtFirstName.Text = "" Then
                MessageBox.Show("First Name Is required")
            ElseIf txtLastName.Text = "" Then
                MessageBox.Show("Last Name Is required")
            Else
                Dim con As New SqlConnection(CS)
                con.Open()
                Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("UPDATE Customers SET FIrstName = @FName, LastName = @LName, PhoneNumber = @PhNumber WHERE Id = @Id", con)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", id)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FName", txtFirstName.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LName", txtLastName.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhNumber", txtPhoneNumber.Text)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MessageBox.Show("Customer has been edited.")
                con.Close()
            End If
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(Me, ex.Message, "Save Failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub btnCancel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCancel.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub CustomerForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If editMode = False Then
        GetId()
    Else
        textId.Text = id
        txtFirstName.Text = FName
        txtLastName.Text = LName
        txtPhoneNumber.Text = PhNumber
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub GetId()
    Dim con As New SqlConnection(CS)
    con.Open()
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT MAX(id)+1 FROM Customers")
    textId.Text = FillDataTable().Rows(0)(0).ToString()
    If textId.Text = "" Then
        textId.Text = "1"
    End If

End Sub

Public Property CommandText As String
    Get
        Return CommandText
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        CommandText = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Sub OpenDBConnection()
    objConnection = New SqlConnection(CS)
    objConnection.Open()
End Sub


Public Sub CreateCommandObject()
    objSqlCommand = objConnection.CreateCommand()
    objSqlCommand.CommandText = CommandText
    objSqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
End Sub

Public Function FillDataTable() As DataTable
    objDataTable = New DataTable()
    objSqlCommand.CommandText = CommandText
    objSqlCommand.Connection = objConnection
    objSqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    objDataTable.Load(objSqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
    objConnection.Close()
    Return objDataTable
End Function

Public Sub CloseConnection()
    If objConnection IsNot Nothing Then objConnection.Close()
End Sub

End Class
```

**MainForm.vb**

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel

Public Class MainForm
Private Sub ExitToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ExitToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub AddToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AddToolStripMenuItem.Click
    CustomerForm.ShowDialog()
End Sub

Private Sub AddToolStripMenuItem1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AddToolStripMenuItem1.Click
    ProductForm.ShowDialog()
End Sub

Private Sub ViewProductsToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ViewProductsToolStripMenuItem.Click
    ManageProductsForm.ShowDialog()
End Sub

Private Sub AboutToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AboutToolStripMenuItem.Click
    AboutForm.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub MainForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'ProductsDatabase2DataSet1.Customers' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.CustomersTableAdapter.Fill(Me.ProductsDatabase2DataSet1.Customers)

End Sub

Private Sub gridCustomers_MouseUp(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles gridCustomers.MouseUp
    Try
        Dim f As CustomerForm = New CustomerForm()
        f.editMode = True
        Dim rowIndex As Integer = gridCustomers.CurrentCell.RowIndex
        f.id = gridCustomers.Rows(rowIndex).Cells("colId").Value.ToString()
        f.FName = gridCustomers.Rows(rowIndex).Cells("colFirstName").Value.ToString()
        f.LName = gridCustomers.Rows(rowIndex).Cells("colLastName").Value.ToString()
        f.PhNumber = gridCustomers.Rows(rowIndex).Cells("colPhoneNumber").Value.ToString()
        f.Show()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub



Private Sub gridCustomers_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles gridCustomers.CellContentClick
    Dim f As CustomerForm = New CustomerForm()
    f.ShowDialog(Me)
    f.editMode = True
End Sub
End Class
```

*Error Message:*
[image]

*Customer Info not displayed:*
[image]

Comment: I don't see where you're setting the `CommandText` property, which the used in `FillDataTable()`, called by `GetId()`. You also have a nasty bug there: the `CommandText` property is recursively calling itself in `Set(ByVal value As String) CommandText = value` (the same applies to C# code, of course). Use an auto-property or a backing field. Use public properties instead ofpublic  fields. Beware of  VB.Net's default instance of a Form.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I actually thought my code was actually going to be way worse than I thought. I was calling CustomerForm 2 times, found out I do not need `f.ShowDialog(Me)` .

Comment: Yes, you also have an overlapping code issue in `gridCustomers_MouseUp` and `gridCustomers_CellContentClick` (also, `f.editMode = True` is called after `ShowDialog()`, so it's not set). So a Cell click will call the same Form twice (this should be quite visible). Fix the other things first, those are a game over.

Comment: You know you can edit and add to a DataGridView's data in place with DataTable, DataAdapter and bindings. Check the Update and Fill methods. No second Form and less code.

Comment: I am getting an error when adding customer, in debugging I get an error "System.InvalidOperationException: 'ExecuteReader: Connection property has not been initialized." on `objDataTable.Load(objSqlCommand.ExecuteReader())`. Editing shows no error. Also I did change CommandText property to `Public Property CommandText As String`. I commented out `gridCustomers_CellContentClick` method as it is still working without it. I did not know that I am able to click anywhere to edit, so it is like I am not even using the link label edit.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, it seems like you have several things potentially going on.

The first thing I would change is your public sql objects. You don't need them to be public. It also increases the chances for issues if you're using the same objects in multiple places.

SqlCommand, SqlConnection, and SqlDataAdapters can be immediately disposed of (in most cases) as soon as they are used.

One easy method to handling all of that is to throw everything inside of a USING block.

```
Dim sqlResult As New Datatable()

Using cn As New SqlConnection("Connection String here"),
                  cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, cn),
                  adapt As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)

            cn.Open()

            'Handle stored procedure vs select options
            If sql.Contains("SELECT") Then
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            Else
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            End If

            'If parameters passed, else comment out
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parameterName", parameterValue)

            sqlResult = New DataTable(cmd.CommandText)
            adapt.Fill(sqlResult)

        End Using
```

Now all your objects are disposed of as soon as your datatable is filled.

*This example uses a datatable, but it is the same idea for anything interacting with sql objects.

If implemented, you may find out that some objects weren't being disposed of or initialized properly.

Another method for testing where things are going wrong is to query the states of the SQL objects before or around the error to see if something isn't set correctly or is uninitialized.